Literature request - Dual quaternion dynamics
In my engineering practice, quaternions turned out to be much more practical than trigonometric rotation matrixes. I learned from this book on quaternions and dynamics how to describe rotation and angular velocity using them, which helped me also to understand Madgwick's quaternion filter for inertial measurement units.
Recently I discovered the concept of dual quaternions. It uses both quaternions and dual numbers to rotate and translate a vector. However, I couldn't find any book on dual quaternion dynamics. I suspect it would help me solve some problems I encounter in my practice.
Please recommend literature on rigid body motion described using dual quaternions. I would like to know the link between a dual quaternion and the velocity (and even acceleration) of a rigid body in motion.
Note that I already found this post. However, I am looking for more literature on this topic if there is.

A Google search turned up a number of hits, including this one A Review on the Applications of Dual Quaternions

This paper has great references. It even has the section Differential Kinematics of Rigid Bodies.  Thank you very much! :D
